# Asp.net Core 3.1 HttpContext.Session.GetString("Index")

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have just started with asp.net Core 3.1 and ran into a problem with using the Session variable(s) to store user login data, basically it returns 'null' randomly when switching between pages or doing an ajax post. I have spend hours on this googling and trying everything I have seen, to no avail. I eventually created a new Razor page web app and I still get the problem with the session variables returning null. To re-produce this, click on the 'Save Changes' button, it will do the HTTP Post, and the session variable 'Index' is null.

I hope someone can help here.

````
<HTML>

@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("body").on("click", ".Save", function (e) {

            if (confirm("Do you want to Save all your changes?")) {

                var bd = ["test:", "mike"];
                

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Index?handler=Fred",
                    cache: false,
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                    },
                    data: JSON.stringify(bd),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (r) {
                        $("body").html(r);
                        alert("Update Completed");
                    },
                    error: function (result) { alert("error " + result.statusText) }
                });
            }
        });
     </script>

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>first time to this page [ @ViewData["firsttime"].]</p>
    <p>times to the page [ @ViewData["count"].]</p>
    <p>session ID [ @HttpContext.Session.Id]</p>
    <br />
    <p>times posted [ @ViewData["post"].]</p>
    <a class="Save btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" href="javascript:;">Save Changes</a>
</div>

<HTML>
```     
        Startup.cs
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
                services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
                services.AddSession(o =>
                {
                    o.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
                    o.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                    o.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
                });
                services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");
                services.AddRazorPages();
        }

                public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseSession();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
```

```Index.chtml.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Data;

namespace Grid.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            if (HttpContext.Session.GetString("Index") == null)
            {
                ViewData["firsttime"] = "yes";
                ViewData["count"] = 1;
                HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("Index", 1);
                HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("Count", 1);
                HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("Post", 0);
                ViewData["post"] = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                ViewData["firsttime"] = "no";
                int? i = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("Count");
                ViewData["count"] = i++;
                ViewData["post"] = 0;
                HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("Count", (int)i);
            }
        }
        public void OnPostFred([FromBody] object bd)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Session.GetString("Index") == null)
            {
                int? i = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("Post");
                ViewData["post"] = i++;
                HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("Post", (int)i);
            }
            else
            {
                ViewData["firsttime"] = "session gone";
            }
        }
    }
}
```
````

Answer (score 1):

In .Net Core, You can access the session through `IHttpContextAccessor`.
To enable that, you need to add `HttpContextAccessor` in your service collection in `ConfigureServices` method in Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
            services.AddSession(o =>
            {
                o.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
                o.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                o.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });
            services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");
            services.AddRazorPages();
        }
```

Now in your `IndexModel` page constructor, you can inject the dependencies

```
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;
        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger,IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }
```

You can Set/Get Session on any page like this

```
public void OnGet()
        {
            if (httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("Index") == null)
            {
                ViewData["firsttime"] = "yes";
                ViewData["count"] = 1;
                httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("Index", 1);
                httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("Count", 1);
                httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("Post", 0);
                ViewData["post"] = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                ViewData["firsttime"] = "no";
                int? i = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("Count");
                ViewData["count"] = i++;
                ViewData["post"] = 0;
                httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("Count", (int)i);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did exactly what you said. So I start the project in visual studio in debug mode. On the index page I click on the privacy page, then back to the index page. The Session remains intact. See the HTML taken from F12

`````
````
<HTML>

    <html lang="en"><head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Home page - Grid</title>
        <link href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="></script>
    
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
                <div class="container">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Grid</a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-label="Toggle navigation" type="button" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="/">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div class="container">
            <main class="pb-3" role="main">
    
                
    
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("body").on("click", ".Save", function (e) {
    
                if (confirm("Do you want to Save all your changes?")) {
    
                    var bd = ["test:", "mike"];
                    var i = 0;
    
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/Index?handler=Fred",
                        cache: false,
                        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                            xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                                $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                        },
                        data: JSON.stringify(bd),
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (r) {
                            $("body").html(r);
                            alert("Update Completed");
                        },
                        error: function (result) { alert("error " + result.statusText) }
                    });
                }
            });
         </script>
    
    <div class="text-center">
       
        <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
        <p>first time to this page [ no.]</p>
        <p>times to the page [ 3.]</p>
        <p>session ID [ 33b3e934-206d-0aa8-3db4-0cee6d41a5cf]</p>
        <br>
        <p>times posted [ 0.]</p>
        <a class="Save btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" href="javascript:;">Save Changes</a>
    </div>
    
            </main>
        </div>
    
        <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
            <div class="container">
                © 2020 - Grid - <a href="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
            </div>
        </footer>
    
        <script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/site.js?v=dLGP40S79Xnx6GqUthRF6NWvjvhQ1nOvdVSwaNcgG18"></script>
        <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CfDJ8GWv3jmnhshAiL19koM-TGi70Yrjt9_nk_EMCmtKd31IWu5kaP9L9bTKTJSNa0M0YxwaUcmaK2pyZBJ9HDIEebyG7OtRRXZAPkWZ-Jxkj3lcmiAFTl1E3R5TOo1taZRzKJbYP-HwcNasWbPwRdv5Uds">
        
    
    
    </body></html>

<HTML>

````
`````

I then click on 'save changes' which does the ajax post and the session("Index") is null. So this is the problem. See the HTML after the ajax post

`````
````
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home page - Grid</title>
    <link href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="></script>

</head>
<body>



    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home page - Grid</title>
    <link href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="></script>



    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Grid</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-label="Toggle navigation" type="button" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="/">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main class="pb-3" role="main">

            

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("body").on("click", ".Save", function (e) {

            if (confirm("Do you want to Save all your changes?")) {

                var bd = ["test:", "mike"];
                var i = 0;

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Index?handler=Fred",
                    cache: false,
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                    },
                    data: JSON.stringify(bd),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (r) {
                        $("body").html(r);
                        alert("Update Completed");
                    },
                    error: function (result) { alert("error " + result.statusText) }
                });
            }
        });
     </script>

<div class="text-center">
   
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>first time to this page [ session gone.]</p>
    <p>times to the page [ .]</p>
    <p>session ID [ 33b3e934-206d-0aa8-3db4-0cee6d41a5cf]</p>
    <br>
    <p>times posted [ .]</p>
    <a class="Save btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" href="javascript:;">Save Changes</a>
</div>

        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            © 2020 - Grid - <a href="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/site.js?v=dLGP40S79Xnx6GqUthRF6NWvjvhQ1nOvdVSwaNcgG18"></script>
    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CfDJ8GWv3jmnhshAiL19koM-TGilawv_ADn2Bqy2OpVOX7UV3GoyvfC_Nk8KhmRUSvic3XHPq3ID73pBHt5s_UchzAooDOM9IvyyMX2fHn-sV8_n_26OLNgvNmJrukJyQPDJg4ICpAbMdqBoRDsIsk6lXI4">
    


</body></html>

````
`````

Comment: have you put any breakpoints in your ```OnPostFred``` method? then you can understand how you getting ```session gone.``` message. Instead of posting answer you can update your question or add comment to the answer you are replying

Comment: Yes, I have done that. What I have found is that it is intermittent. It fails randomly so I cant see how it can be used reliably. I have never had this problem with asp.net. What other method is there for storing session data?

Comment: ```HttpSessionState.Timeout``` Have a look this, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout?view=netframework-4.8